# C# Recursion, Decedents Count Not working

Tags: c#, recursion, parent-child

I have made a smaller sample for my problem, I am trying to get the decedents of each node, but its calculating the decedents count as 0(node0, node1) except the lowest level nodes(node3)? Any help would be appreciable, thanks in advance.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var node3 = new Node
        {
            Id = 3,
            Children = new List<Node>()
        };
        var n2Children = new List<Node>();
        n2Children.Add(node3);
        var node2 = new Node
        {
            Id = 2,
            Children = n2Children
        };
        var n1Children = new List<Node>();
        n1Children.Add(node2);

        var node1 = new Node
        {
            Id = 0,
            Children = n1Children
        };
        SetDecendents(node1);
        Console.WriteLine(node1.Decendents);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static int SetDecendents(Node n)
    {
        if (n.Children.Count() == 0)
        {
            n.Decendents = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            n.Children.Sum(c => SetDecendents(c));
        }
        return n.Decendents;
    }
}

public class Node
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Decendents { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Node> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I see you are setting nodes with no children to have a count of 1 descendants. So each nodes descendants count should include itself? i.e. are your expected results node 1: 2, node 2: 1, node 3: 0? Or  node 1: 3, node 2: 2, node 3: 1?

Comment: That's right, I am including the node itself in the decedents count as well. I would like to have results as node 1: 3, node 2: 2, node 3: 1

Comment: Set Descendants has to enumerate through all children recursively.  A child may have multiple children.  You are only enumerating through the root node for children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are seeing 0 as the result for all nodes except the leaf nodes is that each call to the function `SetDecendents` returns a value (`n.Decendents`) but the caller doesn't use that value for anything. It should be used as part of calculating the caller's `n.Decendents`.

There is one more change required within `SetDecendents` when calculating the number of descendants. As well as summing the node's children, you need to add 1 for the node itself.

```
public static int SetDecendents(Node n)
{
    if (n.Children.Count() == 0)
    {
        n.Decendents = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        n.Decendents = 1 + n.Children.Sum(c => SetDecendents(c));
    }
    return n.Decendents;
}
```

This can be simplified to:

```
public static int SetDecendents(Node n)
{
    n.Decendents = 1 + n.Children.Sum(c => SetDecendents(c));
    return n.Decendents;
}
```

Edit: below is a version where each node count does not includes itself in the count, which the OP has clarified is nottheir use case.

```
public static int SetDecendents(Node n)
{
    if (n.Children.Count() == 0)
    {
        n.Decendents = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        n.Decendents = n.Children.Count() + n.Children.Sum(c => SetDecendents(c));
    }
    return n.Decendents;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `SetDecendents` method had some incorrect logic. Should have been:

```
public static int SetDecendents(Node n)
{
    if (n.Children.Count() == 0)
    {
        n.Decendents = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        n.Decendents = n.Children.Count() + n.Children.Sum(c => SetDecendents(c));
    }

    return n.Decendents;
}
```

Full working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6KPeXF

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var node3 = new Node
        {
            Id = 3,
            Children = new List<Node>()
        };

        var n2Children = new List<Node>();
        n2Children.Add(node3);

        var node2 = new Node
        {
            Id = 2,
            Children = n2Children
        };

        var n1Children = new List<Node>();
        n1Children.Add(node2);

        var node1 = new Node
        {
            Id = 1,
            Children = n1Children
        };

        var n0Children = new List<Node>();
        n0Children.Add(node1);

        var node0 = new Node
        {
            Id = 0,
            Children = n0Children
        };

        SetDecendents(node0);
        Console.WriteLine(node0.Decendents);

        SetDecendents(node1);
        Console.WriteLine(node1.Decendents);

        SetDecendents(node2);
        Console.WriteLine(node2.Decendents);

        SetDecendents(node3);
        Console.WriteLine(node3.Decendents);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static int SetDecendents(Node n)
    {

        if (n.Children.Count() == 0)
        {
            n.Decendents = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            n.Decendents = n.Children.Count() + n.Children.Sum(c => SetDecendents(c));
        }

        return n.Decendents;
    }
}

public class Node
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Decendents { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Node> Children { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit:**

If you want the node itself included in the decedents count (as mentioned in your comments) simply change it to this:

```
public static int SetDecendents(Node n)
{
    if (n.Children.Count() == 0)
    {
        n.Decendents = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        n.Decendents = n.Children.Count() + n.Children.Sum(c => SetDecendents(c));
    }

    return n.Decendents;
}
```